# Creating a function which returns certain value

Tags: r, rstudio

I have this exercise and I cant figure it out.

> Create a function `ans(x, y, c)` which returns the value `c*x^2*y`, if `x^2 <= y <= 1`, and the value `0` otherwise. When you are ready input `c`.

I have 2 different solutions but I can't quite understand how to organize the function correctly. Neither one is correct.

Solution 1)

```
ans <- function(x,y,c){

if (x^2 <= y && <= 1)

return(c*x^2*y)

}

else{

return(0)

}
```

Solution 2)

```
ans <- function(x,y,c){

 if (x^2 <= y & y <= 1)

 return(c*x^2*y)

 else if(x^2 <= 1){

 return(c*x^2*y)

 }

 else{}

 return(0)

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the format of your function. Here may be something you want:

```
ans <- function(x,y,c){
  if (x^2 <= y & y <= 1){
    return(c*x^2*y)
}else{return(0)}}
```